# Как эффективно рассортировать IPv4 адреса на географическую принадлежность

Tags: ip, ip-address, geoip

Есть роутер который я заставил собирать в файлик адреса всех кто стучится мне на RDP, для того чтобы их блокировать.
Но за последние 2 месяца среднее кол-во адресов в неделю выросло на 30%, как раз после видео овербафера в котором он рассказывает про сканеры портов.
Так вот возникла идея просканировать все списки адресов за пол года и посмотреть процент адресов из географии СНГ.
Все адреса разделены при помощи переноса строки.

Comment: Был вариант,  использовать сервис IPapi но это медленно.

Comment: *собирать в файлик адреса всех кто стучится мне на RDP, для того чтобы их блокировать.* Обычно делают наоборот - блочат всех, кому не разрешено...

Comment: Если интересуют только страны то есть официальные файлы регистратур. Например по Евразии ftp://ftp.ripe.net/ripe/stats/delegated-ripencc-latest

Answer (score 0):

Скачать бесплатные [geoip-базы](https://dev.maxmind.com/ru/geolite2/) и при помощи [API на python](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-python) распарсить свой список. Либо выбрать любой другой [поддерживаемый API](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/).